# Changing post type slug to '/' breaks all pages

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

When I do something like:

```
if ('procedures' === $post_type && is_array($args)) {
  $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = '/';
}
```

The procedures **post type** page url's work as it should -- but the standard pages get a 404 that are not within the post type.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way.

> `register_post_type_args`
>    filter can be used to modify post type arguments

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'procedures' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = '/';
    }

    return $args;
}
```